# Robot framework: how to point to libraries folder other than default?

Tags: maven, selenium-webdriver, robotframework

I've set up a Maven project that uses Selenium (as a dependency) and would like to add Robot. The thing is, according to http://robotframework.org/MavenPlugin/:

> Third party libraries (e.g. Selenium Library) can be added to
>   ${project.basedir}/src/test/resources/robotframework/libraries. Java
>   dependencies can be expressed as dependencies to the Robotframework
>   maven plugin configuration in pom.xml.

However, Maven stores the Selenium dependencies in its own repository.

Is there a way to tell Robot "this is where you'll find the libraries you'll need"? As it won't find them within the project structure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a way to tell Robot "this is where you'll find the libraries
>   you'll need"? As it won't find them within the project structure.

This is documented in the user guide, in a section titled [Configuring where to search libraries and other extensions](http://robotframework.org/robotframework/latest/RobotFrameworkUserGuide.html#configuring-where-to-search-libraries-and-other-extensions)

In short, you can set the environment variable `PYTHONPATH`, or you can use the command line option `--pythonpath`.